# Is it necessary to run pg_ctlcluster stop on Ubuntu 16.04 before shutting down?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pg-ctl

I haven't run

```
pg_ctlcluster stop
```

or

```
pg_ctl stop
```

or

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql@9.6-main
```

before rebooting since I installed Postgres on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I'm wondering if I've been lucky (since I've detected no database problems) or whether an Ubuntu shut down does an orderly shut down of Postgres.

Comment: I bet postgres is designed to survive even an unexpected power failure. If it works for you, don't look for others' blessing.

Comment: The way the OS is designed in an reboot or shutdown event is it sends a kill term signal for each running application and service it is up to the application/service handle it in an appropriate way. The OS only complete shuts down when all services sends its "ok, I'm good to go down" to the OS. And surely PostgreSQL handles it just nicely that you don't need to worry about it.